How to model evolution of quantum systems in Hilbert space?
If we let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space of all quantum states. Can one use something like $C^1(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{H})$, the space of continuous differentiable functions from the real numbers to H, to model all possible particles whose states evolve according to the Schrodinger equation?
Or what is typically used to model all possible particles whose states, in some Hilbert space, evolve according to the Schrodinger equation? I couldn't find this online.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Quantum_mechanics

@hft Yes Hilbert Spaces are used to model all the quantum states as I said in my question but not how the quantum states are evolving.

Your question is unclear

The states evolve in time according to the schrodinger equation... what else do you need to know?

@hft whether this space of time-dependent states can be modeled by C^1(R, H)

So you are asking whether every possible differentiable path through the state space satisfies  schrodinger's equation?  In other words, you are asking whether the schrodinger equation is equivalent to the equation $0=0$?  No, it is not.

The question is sufficiently clear in my view and it is also interesting: I voted to reopen it.  In principle the right space is $C^0(\mathbb{R},H)$ but, if we restrict to the set of initial states which belong to the domain of the Hamiltonian operator, their evolutions stay in $C^1(\mathbb{R}, H)$. The issue is of physical nature. Can we assume as physically meaningful states whose everaged energy is infinite?

@ValterMoretti :  I understood the OP to be asking whether every $C^1$ function satisfies the Schrodinger equation, but it does now seem probable that he was actually asking whether candidates for solutions are all $C^1$, in which case I agree with you about reopening.  It would be good if the OP could clarify.

I think he is asking what is the set of the stories of quantum systems.  Also  in the present form of the question, the issue is interesting. On account of Stone's theorem $C^1(\mathbb{R}, {\cal H})$ is allowable only for states which stay in the domain of the Hamiltonian $H$. Otherwise only $C^0$ is possible. If $\psi \not \in D(H)$, in particular $\langle H\rangle_\psi$ is not defined. Can we accept these states? If not, what is the rason why we deal with the whole Hilbert space?

Already the Sch. Equation gives the evolution of every possible quantum state (provided that it can be used as a reasonable "initial condition"). I do not fully understand the question but I voted to reopen as I am curious (still, please edit the question to explain why "the sch. Eq." is not already an answer). My understanding is that you want to know which is the space of all curves in the Hilbert space that are defined by solutions of the Sch. Eq, right?

@Willo Well, I see also your point. It is not clear if the issue is If every curve in $C^0$ or $C^1$ is a possible evolution, or which space of $C^0$ and $C^1$ is suitable for describing time evolutions (even if not necessarily  all curves in these spaces are evolutions). However all that can be clarified  in an articulate answer keeping the question as it stand.

According to the discussion developed above, the question can be considered from a twice perspective at least.
On one hand, the question may concern the issue if the family of all evolutions of quantum states $\mathbb{R} \ni t \mapsto \psi_t \in {\cal H}$ in the Hilbert space describing a quantum system may exhaust the space $C^k(\mathbb{R}, {\cal H})$, for some $k=0,1$. The answer is negative. The reason is that quantum evolutions are curves of special type that are solutions (or limits of solutions) of a special well-known linear equation. Obviously I am referring to the Schroedinger one.
On the other hand, one may wonder if there is $k=0,1,2,\ldots$ such that   $C^k(\mathbb{R}, {\cal H})$ includes all possible quantum evolutions of any state of the considered system (and not only these curves as said above).
This second version has some interesting physical implications which deserve to be briefly discussed.
I will only consider the stationary case, where time evolution is described by a (strongly continuous) one-parameter group of unitary operators and not by a groupoid of these operators. In physical terms I will focus attention on the case of a Hamiltonian operator $H=H^\dagger : D(H) \to {\cal H}$ which do not depend on time. I will indicate by $P^{(H)}$ the spectral measure of $H$, so that
$$H= \int_{\sigma(H)} \lambda dP^{(H)}(\lambda)\:,$$ according to the spectral theorem. $\sigma(H) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is the spectrum of $H$: the set of the values of that observable. (And I also henceforth assume e $\hbar=1$.)
In this case, if $\psi \in {\cal H}$ represents a state, its temporal evolution is, where $e^{-itH}$ is defined by the spectral calculus,
$$\psi_t = e^{-itH} \psi \tag{1}$$
It is easy to prove that the curve $\mathbb{R} \ni t \mapsto \psi_t$ belong to
$C^0(\mathbb{R}, {\cal H})$ for all choices of $\psi \in {\cal H}$. In other words the one-parameter group $\{e^{-itH}\}_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ is strongly continuous.
Is it possible to improve $C^0(\mathbb{R}, {\cal H})$ to $C^1(\mathbb{R}, {\cal H})$?
Due to Stone theorem, $\mathbb{R} \ni t \mapsto \psi_t$ defined as in (1) is differentiable, if and only if $\psi \in D(H)$, which is a dense domain in ${\cal H}$. However $D(H)= {\cal H}$ if and only if $H$ is bounded. Physically, it means that the permitted values of the energy (the elements of $\sigma(H)$) form a bounded set. This is not the case for the most part of the quantum systems. Therefore the improvement  $C^0(\mathbb{R}, {\cal H})$ to $C^1(\mathbb{R}, {\cal H})$ is not allowed in general. Notice that here mere differentiability implies $C^1$ since, again from Stone's theorem, the celebrated Schroedinger equation is valid if $\psi \in D(H)$. In that case, also $\psi_t \in D(H)$ and
$$\frac{d\psi_t}{dt} = -i H \psi_{t} = -ie^{-itH} H\psi$$
and the right-most side defines a $t$-continuous function by construction. The apparent conclusion is that, in general, there is no chance to improve $C^0(\mathbb{R}, {\cal H})$ to $C^1(\mathbb{R}, {\cal H})$.
However that is not the whole story. In fact, $\psi \not \in D(H)$ has some important physical implication.
$\psi \not \in D(H)$ is equivalent to
$$\int_{\sigma(H)} |\lambda|^2 d \langle \psi| P^{(H)}(\lambda) \psi \rangle = +\infty\:.$$
In physical terms, this implies that the state represented by the (normalized) vector has no finite standard deviation $\Delta_\psi H$ of the energy.
A more superficial scrutiny would also imply that the same expectation value $\langle H\rangle_\psi$ of the energy is not finite. Indeed folklore states that
$$\langle H\rangle_\psi = \langle \psi|H\psi\rangle \tag{2}\:.$$
However (2) is valid only if $\psi \in D(H)$, but the general definition of $\langle H\rangle_\psi$ is
$$\langle H\rangle_\psi = \int_{\sigma(H)} \lambda d \langle \psi| P^{(H)}(\lambda) \psi \rangle$$
which only needs $\psi \in D(\sqrt{|H|}) \supset D(H)$.
These considerations are related to the longstanding issue whether or not  all unit vectors  of ${\cal H}$ are, in practice,  real states of the system, i.e. physically conceivable. (E.g. can we consider  physical a state whose expectation energy is infinite? Or such that its standard deviation diverges?)
From the pure mathematical side, another related issue pops up here. Are there states $\psi \in {\cal H}$ whose evolution is  even $C^\infty$?
The answer is positive: it is sufficient to consider states whose energy content (referred to $H$) is bounded: the ones which belong to the subspace spanned  by the spectral projectors over a bounded interval $[a,b] \subset \sigma(H)$. In that case the evolution is even analytic.
